# SQL Server: copy, replace and paste within same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am pretty new to SQL and hope someone can help me with the following general question.

I have a large table with several columns where I want to do 3 things via one stored procedure:

1. Select all data for country Great Britain (GB), e.g. by using something like the following:

   ```
   SELECT *
   FROM   XYZ_TableData
   WHERE  (countryCode LIKE 'GB')
   ```
2. Copy all the above to a temp table and replace 'GB' in column countryCode by 'XX'.
3. Copy the data from the temp table and insert it into the above table (i.e. with the copied data showing XX instead of GB).

Can anyone help me to get a start here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it all in one step, no temp table required:

```
insert into mytable(field1,field2,field3,country) 
  select field1,field2,field3,'XX' As Country from mytable where country='GB'
```

This assumes you are trying to append a new set of records to the table, not update the pre-existing records. I read the question one way, but Theresa read it another...guess you need to decide what you meant.

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I meant - thanks a lot for the quick reply.

Answer (score 1):

Why aren't you doing an UPDATE?

```
UPDATE XYZ_TableData
SET countryCode = 'XX'
WHERE countryCode = 'GB'
```

Comment: An update will replace the GB rows though, not make XX rows in addition to the GB ones.

Comment: Ah, yes.  I see what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, Theresa - I was looking for something to copy it, not to edit it so the above covers it perfectly. :-)